# Android 5 kill -9 <PID> doesn't work

Tags: android, shell

Device is rooted. Can't kill this proccess neither it hangs nor working

```
ps | grep spi1
root 452 2 0 0 c0051a18 00000000 S spi1
kill -9 452

ps | grep spi1
root 452 2 0 0 c0051a18 00000000 S spi1
```

Comment: where is the question description?

Comment: are you running as root?

Comment: Yes. su works fine.